# Why std::count is slower that plain for loop with MSVC Compiler but equal with GCC?

Tags: c++, vectorization

I am testing the performance of the C++ standard library algorithms and encountered a weird thing.

Here is my code to compare the performance of std::count vs plain for loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;


int my_count(const std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    int num = 0;

    for (int i: v) {
        if (i == val)
            num++;
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int total_count = 0;

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(100000000);

    // Fill vector
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v[i] = i % 10000;
    }

    int val = 1;

    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        total_count += std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << "std::count time:   " << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        total_count += my_count(v, val);
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::cout << "my_count   time:   " << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << std::endl;
    }

    // We need this so the compiler does not prune the code above
    std::cout << "Total items: " << total_count << std::endl;
}
```

With MinGW I get this:

```
std::count time:   65827
my_count   time:   64861
```

And with MSVC I get a pretty weird result:

```
std::count time:   65532
my_count   time:   28584
```

The MinGW result seems reasonable since, as far as I know, STL count function if roughly equal to the plain for loop, but the MSVC result seems weird - why the plain for loop is more than 2x faster than std::count?

These results are reproducible on my machine - it's not something that occurs once, but it occurs each time I run the code. I even tried changing the function order, running multiple `for` loops to avoid caching or branch prediction bias, but I still get the same result.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: How do you compile the code? Debug or release mode; flags?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  How did you compile the code?

Comment: I use the Release mode with no special flags. I use CMake and the only option there is set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

Comment: What happens if you switch the order and first execute your count? Or execute them multiple times one after another in the same program?

Comment: I get the same result if I change the order or execute it multiple times one after another. I tried it, but did not include here for simplicity.

Comment: There is no need to run the code: a short look at generated assemebly clearly shows that MSVC vectorizes your function, but is unable to do this for `std::count`. Btw if you change the return value from `int` to `size_t` (as is true for `std::count`), you will get the same slowdown for your code.

Comment: Oh, wow! Seem reasonable to vectorize the code here. Interesting, that size_t behaves differently, though. I should explore the issue in depth, for sure. Thanks, @StaceyGirl!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because MSVC vectorizes your manually written code, but is unable to do the same for `std::count`.

This is how vectorized code looks:

```
        movdqa  xmm5, XMMWORD PTR __xmm@00000001000000010000000100000001
        and     rcx, -8
        xorps   xmm3, xmm3
        xorps   xmm2, xmm2
        npad    3
$LL4@my_count:
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        add     r8, 8
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm5
        paddd   xmm0, xmm3
        pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm4
        pand    xmm0, xmm1
        pandn   xmm1, xmm3
        movdqa  xmm3, xmm0
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm5
        por     xmm3, xmm1
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2
        movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax+16]
        add     rax, 32                             ; 00000020H
        pcmpeqd xmm1, xmm4
        pand    xmm0, xmm1
        pandn   xmm1, xmm2
        movdqa  xmm2, xmm0
        por     xmm2, xmm1
        cmp     r8, rcx
        jne     SHORT $LL4@my_count
```

You can see how it load 4 ones in `xmm5` register at the beginning. This value will be used to maintain 4 separate counters that track result for 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th DWORDs. Once counting is done, those 4 values will be added together to form the result of the function.

The issue with MSVC vectorizer seems to lie in the fact that counter, data type and argument type should be "compatible":

- Return type should match in size the data type
- Argument type should be equal or less in size to data type

If any of those constraints is not met, the code is not vectorized. This makes sense as if your data type is 32-bit wide you have to operate on 32-bit counters to make them work together, so if your return type is 64-bit wide instead some additional manipulations are required (which is what GCC is able to do, but this still slows down `std::count` compared to manually written loop).

This is the case where manually written loop should be preferred as subtle differences in semantic (`int` return type) make it easier to vectorize (even for GCC, which generates shorter code).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that seems to be an iterator issue.

I've made an extended test:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;


int std_count(const std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    return std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
}

int my_count_for(const std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] == val) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

int my_count_for_in(const std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    int num = 0;

    for (int i : v) {
        if (i == val) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

int my_count_iter(const std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    int num = 0;

    for (auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); i++) {
        if (*i == val) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(1000000);

    // Fill vector
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v[i] = i % 10000;
    }

    int val = 1;

    int num_iters = 1000;

    int total_count = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        {
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; i++) {
                total_count += std_count(v, val);
            }
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
            std::cout << "std::count time:       " << duration.count() << std::endl;
        }

        {
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; i++) {
                total_count += my_count_for(v, val);
            }
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
            std::cout << "my_count_for time:     " << duration.count() << std::endl;
        }

        {
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; i++) {
                total_count += my_count_for_in(v, val);
            }
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
            std::cout << "my_count_for_in time:  " << duration.count() << std::endl;
        }

        {
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; i++) {
                total_count += my_count_iter(v, val);
            }
            auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
            std::cout << "my_count_iter time:    " << duration.count() << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << total_count << std::endl;
    std::cin >> total_count;
}
```

And here's what I get:

```
std::count time:       679683
my_count_for time:     235269
my_count_for_in time:  228185
my_count_iter time:    650714

std::count time:       656192
my_count_for time:     231248
my_count_for_in time:  231050
my_count_iter time:    652598

std::count time:       660295
my_count_for time:     238812
my_count_for_in time:  225893
my_count_iter time:    648812
```

Still seems quite weird that STL function is not the fastest way to solve the task. If someone knows the detailed answer, please share it with me.